# What part of the netty client connect operations should be shared?

Tags: java, netty

While the netty site is well documented and contains a fair amount of sample code, there's something that's not clear to me.

In the [http example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClient.java) (on the netty 4.0 branch), there are a number of steps that are taken to create a single request and retrieve a response. They are:

- Create an SslContext if necessary (if the request is https)
- Create an EventLoopGroup
- Create a Bootstrap
- call bootstrap.group(eventLoopGroup).channel(the channel class).handler(the channel handler).
- call boostrap.connect().channel() to get a channel

It's not clear to me which steps here can be shared and which must be created per request. In particular if I'm running a loop that will be creating a mix of http and https requests, do I need a separate bootstrap with a separate handler for each type (one with the ssl context and one without)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and should) share everything... You can call bootstrap.connect() multiple times.

Comment: An answer from the author! Thanks Norman, and thanks for netty. One further question - in the Http example referenced, you add a channel handler that has an sslContext conditionally appended. How would I handle that with a mix of http and https requests? Doesn't the plain http need a handler w/o the sslContext? I assumed from the docs that the handler is configuring what happens on boostrap.connect, so I'd assume sharing the bootstrap would mean sharing the handler, only the handlers need to behave differently.

Comment: @steve-b consider cloning the bootstrap object to set a different initializer for your https endpoint.